# Ayuda con los eventos del ratón en QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy como hacer ciertos eventos con mi ratón. Ahora lo que quiero es retornar el valor de la instancia pero no se como:
Codigo cpp:

```
#include "mouselogger.h"
#include <QDebug>

MouseLogger &MouseLogger::instance()
{
    static MouseLogger _instance;
    return _instance;
}

MouseLogger::MouseLogger(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Set hook
    mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, hInstance, 0);
    // Check hook is correctly
    if (mouseHook == NULL) {
        qWarning() << "Mouse Hook failed";
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseLogger::mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Q_UNUSED(Code);

    // Having an event hook, we nned to cast argument lParam
    // to the structure of the mouse is the hook.
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

    // Next, we check to see what kind of event occurred,
    // if the structure is not a pointer to nullptr
    if(pMouseStruct != nullptr) {
        switch (wParam) {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            qDebug() << "WM_MOUSEMOVE";
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            qDebug() << "WM_LBUTTONDOWN";
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            qDebug() << "WM_LBUTTONUP";
            break;
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            qDebug() << "WM_RBUTTONDOWN";
            break;
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            qDebug() << "WM_RBUTTONUP";
            break;
        case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
            qDebug() << "WM_MBUTTONDOWN";
            break;
        case WM_MBUTTONUP:
            qDebug() << "WM_MBUTTONUP";
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
            qDebug() << "WM_MOUSEWHEEL";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        emit instance().mouseEvent();
    }

    // After that you need to return back to the chain hook event handlers
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

codigo main():

```
//#include <QCoreApplication>

//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
//{
   // QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //return a.exec();
//}

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mouselogger.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QObject::connect(&MouseLogger::instance(), &MouseLogger::mouseEvent,
                     [](){

        //retornar el valor
        qDebug() << s;
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Me urge esto para un trabajo gracias.

Comment: Deberías releer la pregunta que has escrito. No se trata de que tu, que sabes lo que necesitas, la entiendas... ponte en el lugar de alguien que no tenga ni idea de qué estás hablando. ¿Qué se supone que es `s`? ¿Qué quieres devolver, `s` o `qDebug()`? En esta último caso entiendo que te refieres a `s`, pero como verás no queda demasiado claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que pretendas recuperar `s`, las malas noticias es que no podrás hacerlo con una lambda. Sin embargo nada te impide usar una clase para gestionar la información:

```
class SignalReceiver : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
    /* falta el tipo */ s;

  public:
    SignalReceiver& Instance()
    {
      static SignalReceiver instance;
      return instance;
    }

    s GetS() const
    { return s; }

  public slots:
    void Event(/* Argumentos de MouseLogger::mouseEvent */)
    {
      s = /* lo que sea */
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  SignalReceiver::Instance().connect(&MouseLogger::instance(), &MouseLogger::mouseEvent, &SignalReceiver::Event);

  return a.exec();
}
```

Para conocer el valor de `s` basta con llamar (desde cualquier parte del código) a `SignalReceiver::Instance().GetS()`.

No es un diseño especialmente elegante pero cumple con su comentido. Eso sí, cada evento que entre machacará el valor de `s`. Si no aportas más información es complicado dar una respuesta más acertada.

Un saludo.

Comment: yo por ejemplo quería retornar el movimiento por ejemplo esto "WM_RBUTTONUP" al main desde la funcion LRESULT y pensaba que con la instancia se podía hacer.

Comment: @OmarOmar Lo normal es que conectes la señal con aquellos elementos que deban hacer algo cuando se produce el evento. Como te he comentado en la respuesta, el código que te propongo no es precisamente la mejor forma de solucionar el problema.

Comment: @OmarOmar Por otro lado, las señales pueden enviar parámetros a los slots. Quizás es ese el camino que debes seguir.

Comment: si tienes razon gracias

Comment: al mismo tiempo voy a ser una pregunta sobre VK_Key eventos virtuales por hacer de alguna manera el codigo prolijo puedo hacerlo manualmente pero no megusta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @OmarOmar dado que estas preguntas no solo deberían servirte a tí. Si esta respuesta la das por buena lo suyo sería etiquetarla como tal. Así quien venga detrás con el mismo problema sabrá si esta respuesa le va a servir de algo o no (y esto mismo es aplicable a otras tantas preguntas que has publicado)